# Does polling for file directory changes increases hard disk failure rate?

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I have a requirement to look for creation of files in about a hundred folders. I have been looking at FileSystemWatcher and understands that it is not exactly reliable and may fail. As suggested by some, polling is a more reliable way to detect file changes reliably.

Seeing that polling accesses the hard disk constantly, my main question here is that does polling for directory changes 24/7 increases the rate of hard disk failure dramatically as compared to handling it with FileSystemWatcher?

Comment: Someone more knowledgable can correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that if your folder is indexed, and it's being accessed regularly, the disk itself won't actually be read when checking for a new file.

Answer (score 0):

Most home hard drives are not made for 24/7 operations that's where enterprise class hardware comes in (used in servers), also drives have a MTBF (mean time between failure) as you can see enterprise drives lead the way here. http://download.intel.com/support/motherboards/server/sb/enterprise_class_versus_desktop_class_hard_drives_.pdf , it purely depends on how hard your hitting the drive, as someone mentioned indexing helps, but it you want a robust solution, then you need a robust drive.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, which is does polling of directory causes hard disk failure more often.